# SVM model highlights the wrong data points as support vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm working on an SVM model for a homework. no matter what I do, the model picks the wrong data points as support vectors:
[scatter svm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjV2w.png)

this is my data:
[csv data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIYJdb4TDSvK72P0sdTkcR24DsLsqEYA/view?usp=drive_link)

this is my code:

```
def decision_hyperplane(clf, x, y=None, dimension=2):
    """
    Return a decision line (dimension 2, return y based on x) or a
    decision plane (dimension 3, return z based on x and y).

    Decision plane equation is wx + b = 0, so in 2d case:
    w.dot(x) + b = w_x * x + w_y * y + b = 0
    y = (-w_x * x - b) / w_y
    """
    if dimension == 2:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x) / clf.coef_[0][1]
    elif dimension == 3:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x - clf.coef_[0][1] * y) / clf.coef_[0][2]


file_path = 'cell_samples.csv'  # Replace with the actual file path
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
x_column= 'UnifSize'
y_column= 'UnifShape'
class_name = 'Class'
X = df[[x_column, y_column]]
y = df[class_name]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=255)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=100000)
# fit the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

#scatter data points
plt.scatter(X_test[x_column][y_pred == 2], X_test[y_column][y_pred == 2], label='Type 1', c='blue', marker='o')
plt.scatter(X_test[x_column][y_pred == 4], X_test[y_column][y_pred == 4], label='Type 2', c='red', marker='s')

w = clf.coef_[0] # parameters  of the hyperplane
b = clf.intercept_ #hyperplane interception
a = -(w[1] / w[0])
xx = np.linspace(X_test.iloc[:, 0].min(), X_test.iloc[:, 0].max())
yy = a * xx - (b / w[0]) # getting corresponding y-points

# plot the decision boundary (hyperplane)
hyperplane = decision_hyperplane(clf, xx)
plt.plot(xx, hyperplane, linewidth=2, color='black')

# Highlight only the closest support vectors
vectors = clf.support_vectors_[np.abs(clf.decision_function(clf.support_vectors_)).argsort()]
# get unique vectors (no duplicates)
vectors = np.unique(vectors, axis=0)

plt.scatter(vectors[:, 0],
            vectors[:, 1],
            s=100, facecolors='none',
            linewidth=1,
            edgecolors='k', alpha=.5,
            marker='o', label='Support Vectors'
            )

# plot description`
plt.title('Scatter plot with SVM Decision Boundary')
plt.xlabel(x_column)
plt.ylabel(y_column)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

from the scatter plot, you can easily see that there are only 4 support vectors.

I tried to use a C value of 100000 but the program lags and takes too long to finish

Comment: Would be good if you can upload your data to google drive or dropbox and then share a link here. After looking at your code, I noticed that you are not scaling your data before training. That might improve some of your problems. Otherwise, why do you want to go with C = 100000? That would probably (or will) lead to overfitting.

Comment: @TinoD I have updated the question with a link to my csv file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIYJdb4TDSvK72P0sdTkcR24DsLsqEYA/view?usp=drive_link)_italic_. 
I only used a C= 100000 because I saw someone suggest that for another person on stackoverflow and thought it might help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support vectors are learnt from the training data, but in the code only the test points were being plotted. I also corrected the part that pulls out the closest unique vectors.

You can run the SVC with default settings (C=1), and get the results below which include both the test and train data:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def decision_hyperplane(clf, x, y=None, dimension=2):
    """
    Return a decision line (dimension 2, return y based on x) or a
    decision plane (dimension 3, return z based on x and y).

    Decision plane equation is wx + b = 0, so in 2d case:
    w.dot(x) + b = w_x * x + w_y * y + b = 0
    y = (-w_x * x - b) / w_y
    """
    if dimension == 2:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x) / clf.coef_[0][1]
    elif dimension == 3:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x - clf.coef_[0][1] * y) / clf.coef_[0][2]


file_path = '../cell_samples.csv'  # Replace with the actual file path
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
x_column= 'UnifSize'
y_column= 'UnifShape'
class_name = 'Class'

X = df[[x_column, y_column]]
y = df[class_name]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=255)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
# fit the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

#train: scatter data points
plt.scatter(X_train[x_column][y_pred_train == 2], X_train[y_column][y_pred_train == 2],
            label='train Type 1', c='darkblue', marker='o', s=50)
plt.scatter(X_train[x_column][y_pred_train == 4], X_train[y_column][y_pred_train == 4],
            label='train Type 2', c='darkred', marker='s', s=50)

#test: scatter data points
plt.scatter(X_test[x_column][y_pred == 2], X_test[y_column][y_pred == 2],
            label='test Type 1', c='dodgerblue', marker='o', s=13)
plt.scatter(X_test[x_column][y_pred == 4], X_test[y_column][y_pred == 4],
            label='train Type 2', c='tomato', marker='s', s=13)

w = clf.coef_[0] # parameters  of the hyperplane
b = clf.intercept_ #hyperplane interception
a = -(w[1] / w[0])
xx = np.linspace(X_test.iloc[:, 0].min(), X_test.iloc[:, 0].max())
yy = a * xx - (b / w[0]) # getting corresponding y-points

# plot the decision boundary (hyperplane)
hyperplane = decision_hyperplane(clf, xx)
plt.plot(xx, hyperplane, linewidth=2, color='black')

# Highlight only the closest support vectors
unique_svs = np.unique(clf.support_vectors_, axis=0)
sv_distances = np.abs(clf.decision_function(unique_svs))
sv_ixs_sorted = sv_distances.argsort()
closest_vectors = unique_svs[sv_ixs_sorted[:20]] #the 20 closest

plt.scatter(
    closest_vectors[:, 0],
    closest_vectors[:, 1],
    s=220,
    # color='black', alpha=0.3, #support vectors single colour
    c=abs(clf.decision_function(closest_vectors)), cmap='bone_r', #shade by distance
    linewidth=3,
    edgecolors='none',
    marker='o', label='Support Vectors',
    zorder=-1
)

# plot description
plt.title('Scatter plot with SVM Decision Boundary')
plt.xlabel(x_column)
plt.ylabel(y_column)
plt.gcf().legend(loc='lower left', ncols=3, bbox_to_anchor=(0.12, 0.1), fontsize=9)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 3.5)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: This would still make a lot of faulty support vectors. I only want the closest points to the hyperplane.

Comment: I've amended the code. The unique vectors are now pulled out *before* being sorted, rather than at the end. The vectors are now coloured by distance from the decision boundary, but you can also change it to a fixed colour.